# Github Actions: Docker compose healthcheck timeout doesn't seem to work

Tags: docker, docker-compose, github-actions

I am trying to setup mysql and node with docker-compose. On every push, I trigger an action which will build & run docker image. I try to wait until db and redis are ready but it looks like git actions doesn't respect the health check timeout as it immediately exits after creating the containers.

See it here: https://youtu.be/iKNo56qngXY

Repo link: https://github.com/axelthat2/testing_actions